# Creating ground in a 2D runner game

Tags: game-engine, game-physics

It may be a repetitive uestion but I could not find any specific answer to my query

How to create A slanted/curved ground in a 2d runner game. The user will see side view like the old game "Mario"

If I use tiled based map I can have only rectangular objects.

What is the best way to create tilted ground? Should I use tiled based map, or should I define corner points in the map and create the ground programatically?

And what are the difficulties in creating curved ground.

And what can be the possible logic while creating game **"Flying Pengui"**
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.topfreegames.penguinfree&feature=related_apps#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEwOSwiY29tLnRvcGZyZWVnYW1lcy5wZW5ndWluZnJlZSJd

Answer (score 1):

> Should I use tiled based map, or should I define corner points in the
>   map and create the ground programatically?

The latter approach is much better. A linear interpolation between corner points will give you the height of the ground at any position.  You just need to fill what's below with your tiles.

> And what are the difficulties in creating curved ground.

It should be easy. All you have to do is replacing the linear interpolation with a higher order one.
This [link](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/cpp_src/spline/spline.html) contains implementation of various spline functions with which you can make a curvy ground.

> And what can be the possible logic while creating game "Flying Pengui"

I see a sin-wave like ground and splines will do the trick. Also, to avoid corner points you can build a repeated quadratic function that matches the shape that you want.